# Thin client list

Tags: thin-clients

Is there a trusted thin client list somewhere?

I searched one for **OSX** and one for **Android** and I found next to nothing. That is: nothing at all for OSX, and only a source-only on github for Android (which I don't know how trustable is anyway).

(I understand "trusted" might mean anything, so let's just keep to "*you* trust it". That is, list it only if you actually use it at the very least)

Comment: The list itself should not be in this question (Stack Exchange is a poor format for lists). I suggest that as an answer, someone either point to an existing list on the wiki, or create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is one light client that works on a Mac - [MultiBit](http://multibit.org/). This client seems to be around for awhile and is open-source, so should be trustworthy.

There a couple wallets working on Android, like [Bitcoin Wallet](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImRlLnNjaGlsZGJhY2gud2FsbGV0Il0.) and [Bitcoin](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bitcoinandroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iaXRjb2luYW5kcm9pZCJd). Personally, can't say much about trustworthiness of either, asides the fact that some high-reputation people on the forum seem to be [promoting it](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=26959.0).

Alternatively, you can try using [eWallets](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aEWallets), as they can be accessed on any device.

Comment: Nice tip about eWallets, it really didn't occur to me! (though of course that's totally a different thing)

Comment: The MultiBit client has the usual Mac features like menus at the top of the screen,  command-Q for quit and the preferences and about MultiBit appear in the expected place. It is packaged up as an app inside a DMG file like other Mac apps. Though it is cross platform Java it is actually developed on a Mac.

Comment: +1 it should also be noted that MultiBit is open source under the MIT license so you can see what's going on under the covers if you really want to satisfy yourself about trustworthiness. Disclaimer: Along with @jim618 I am one of the developers.

Answer (score 1):

[LoveBitcoins.org](http://lovebitcoins.org) has a [list of clients](http://lovebitcoins.org/getStarted.html) for various platforms. Some of them are thin clients that do not have to download the block chain, and they are generally trusted by the community.

Comment: "The domain lovebitcoins.org is for sale" now.

Answer (score 0):

On Android I like BitcoinSpinner. It's thin and fast because you don't need to download the blockchain locally.