# Wallet for btc bot

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, wallet, client, thin-clients

*Which bitcoin wallet should I use to manipulate it programmatically?*

I don't want to use heavy `bitcoin-core`. But as I understand there are different kinds of bitcoin's thin clients: some outsource all jobs to 3rd party server, some of them [take part of verification](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50211/how-a-thin-node-ensures-the-validity-of-blockchain/50216#50216).

My requirements:

1. Bitcoin wallet which can be programmatically manipulated
2. Enough security. The program which will manipulate my wallet will be deployed somewhere in the cloud.
3. It can be tested with testnet, though I'm not sure whether testnet provide you with your own wallet or not

Answer (score 1):

Just about any wallet software should meet your three requirements. Security is something you'll probably have to figure out yourself, for example how you secure your server will probably have a higher chance of being a security hole than any widely used bitcoin library.

You should probably start with which language you want to write your bot in and then find the most widely used bitcoin library for that language.