# Finding private key

Tags: private-key

How do I find the private key in order to transfer my bitcoins from bitcoin core. The block chain keeps crashing before synchronization takes place. Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

if you are on linux then you can use

```
$ bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey youraddress
```

where you replace `youraddress` with your actual bitcoin address. do this for as many addresses as you have to get the private key for each of them.

Comment: im using windows, and "your address" is the address where i have them stored or ?

Comment: `youraddress` is your bitcoin address - eg `1MTChe67xXyAnckt693ZaCk4J3vWyiquFB`. but if you are on windows then i suggest following the comment posted by [Nick ODell](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/2306/nick-odell) below your question.

Comment: so i found the private key., but the situation now is bitcoin is 1 year and 5 weeks out of sync, when i input the private key it gives me it says i have 0 bitcoins, because the data is outdated and is not current enough to show my deposit into this wallet. is there a way around this ?

Comment: i'd say just wait for it to catch up and then you will be able to spend your coins. another possibility is to [use a thin client](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/thin-client-list) so that you don't have to download the blockchain before spending your coins.